# How to make slopes of the same length in PGFPlots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{
    Cus/.style={
        axis equal image, 
        axis lines = center,
        view={0}{90},
        xmin=-4.1, xmax=4.1,
        ymin=-3.1, ymax=3.1,
        domain=-4:4, y domain=-3:3,
        xtick={-4,-3,...,4}, ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
        samples=10
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
    Cus
]
\addplot3[black, quiver={u={1}, v={2*(x-2)*(y+1)}, scale arrows=0.02}] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Slopes]

My question is **how to make every slope of the same length in the graph.** Also, **how can I reduce the font size of the numbers?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your first question, your lines were not normalized. As for your second question, I just followed section 4.7.4 of the pgfmanual.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{
    Cus/.style={
        axis equal image, 
        axis lines = center,
        view={0}{90},
        xmin=-4.1, xmax=4.1,
        ymin=-3.1, ymax=3.1,
        domain=-4:4, y domain=-3:3,
        xtick={-4,-3,...,4}, ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
        samples=10
    }
}
\pgfplotsset{ %<- added
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\tiny},
    legend style={font=\footnotesize},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
    Cus
]
\addplot3[black, quiver={u={1/sqrt(1+4*(x-2)^2*(y+1)^2)}, v={2*(x-2)*(y+1)/sqrt(1+4*(x-2)^2*(y+1)^2)}, scale arrows=0.2}] (x,y,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey marmot, I have not seen you in a while, how are you? Thanks for the response.

It is not clear to me how the lines are normalized. Does it have to do with the ODE? I'm just beginning to see differential equations. I also do not understand why there are two parameters of the `quiver` command: `u` and `v`. I always thought that in `u` we entered 1 and in `v` the differential equation. How do you do to calculate these parameters?

I understood the second answer `:)`, thanks.

Comment: @manooooh Hi, I'm doing fine, still hibernating. How are you? I normalized the lines because I thought you wanted them to be all have the same length.

Comment: Oh that's fine, thanks for unblocking a moment! I'm good, just starting seriously the university. Yes I want it, but I dont how did you calculate that parameters (it does not seem that you have derived or integrated).

Comment: @manooooh Well, if you are longer at the university, you'll learn at which places you are allowed to cheat. ;-) More seriously, all this plot does is to produce a vector field in which the vectors at a given point are specified by u and v. Since I thought that you want all vectors to have the same length, I just divided them by their length `sqrt(u^2+v^2)`.

Comment: marmot please do not take me to places I do not want to go... hahaha. So it was easy! (I think). If I have more problems with this parameters I will let you know (don't wanna you to hibernate `;D`). Have a good day/afternoon